# stop background animation on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover

On jquery I set interval for animate background on one menu link and my code is

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.freesubmiteff').animate({ backgroundColor: "#46B525" }, "slow");
        $('.freesubmiteff').animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, "slow");
        $('.freesubmiteff').animate({ backgroundColor: "#46B525" }, "slow");
        $('.freesubmiteff').animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, "slow");
        }, 1000);
</script>
```

its working fine, but my problem is how i can stop animation on `mouse over` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var fst = $('.freesubmiteff'); //cache selector
function ani() { //animation function
    fst.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#46B525"
    }, "slow");
    fst.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    }, "slow");
    fst.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#46B525"
    }, "slow");
    fst.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    }, "slow");
}
var set_int = window.setInterval(ani, 1000); //creating interval with var name set_ani
fst.hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true); //stop animation on hover element 
    clearInterval(set_int); //clear the inerval
}, function () {
    ani(); //if you want animation function to start as mouse leave happens
    set_int = window.setInterval(ani, 1000); //set interval again on mouse leave
});
```

---

References

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[Window.clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

[Window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: and how i can start interval after mouse leave ?

Comment: @MarkRichards `hover` has two functions 1st `mouse over` 2nd `mouse leave` .

Comment: @MarkRichards Welcome Happy to help :). Added References and explanation give it read .

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `setInterval` to a variable like

```
var interval;
function fun () {
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
                     ......
                    });
}
```

Then clear it using [**Window.clearInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

```
$('.freesubmiteff').on('hover', function () {
     clearInterval(interval);  // happens when mouseover
}, function() {
   fun();     //In callback, start again the animation
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

how about use this?

```
$([selector]).mouseover(function() {
    $(".freesubmiteff").finish();
});
```

see "finish" method in jquery api.

http://api.jquery.com/finish/

you can stop animation use this method..

and you can also use "stop" method like this..

code 1:

```
$(".selector").stop(true, false);
```

code 1 look like stop animation in current state.

code 2:

```
$(".selector").stop(true, true);
```

code 2 look like "finish" animation..